# How to write a Saxon ExtensionFunctionDefinition returning a Node

Tags: xslt, saxon

Using Saxon HE 12, I managed to create a Saxon `ExtensionFunctionDefinition` returning a `SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING` and using it in a XSLT transformation ; but I have a hard time making one returning a Node, let's say a `SequenceType.SINGLE_NODE` for this exemple.

Relevant part of the ExtensionFunctionDefinition extending class is :

```java
    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            @Override
            public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                Processor processor  = new Processor();
                net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = buildSomeDocument();
                XdmNode wrapped = documentBuilder.wrap(document.getFirstChild());
                return wrapped.getUnderlyingNode();
            }
        };
    }
```

where `buildSomeDocument` returns a `org.w3c.dom.Document`

The code compiles fine but execution throws an exception :

```
 SXXP0004  Node returned by extension function was created with an incompatible Configuration
```

How to pass the configuration ?

What would be the simplest way to return a (wrapped) `org.w3c.dom` Element or Node ?

-- edit Creating the Transformer starting from `new Processor()` instead of `TransformerFactory`, `HelloNode` beeing the `ExtensionFunctionDefinition`

The code for the transformation is :

```java
        Processor processor = new Processor();
        processor.registerExtensionFunction(new HelloNode());

        Path xslPath = Path.of("./some/path/to/testjavafunction.xsl");
        XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(xslPath.toFile());
        XsltTransformer xsltTransformer = xsltExecutable.load();

        // xml source
        Path xmlPath = Path.of("./some/path/to/testjavafunction.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlPath.toFile());
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
        Source source = new SAXSource(inputSource);
        xsltTransformer.setSource(source);

        // destination
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Serializer serializerDestination = processor.newSerializer(byteArrayOutputStream);
        xsltTransformer.setDestination(serializerDestination);

        // transform
        xsltTransformer.transform();

        // dbg print
        System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8"));
```

the `call` method is now updated to :

```java
   @Override
   public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
         Configuration.ApiProvider processor0 = context.getConfiguration().getProcessor();
         Processor processor = (Processor)processor0;
         net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document document = makeSomeDOM();

         XdmNode wrapped = documentBuilder.wrap(document.getFirstChild());
         return wrapped.getUnderlyingNode();
   }
```

`makeSomeDom`method is :

```java
private static Document makeSomeDom() {
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = db.newDocument();
 Element h1 = document.createElement("h1");
 h1.setTextContent("my-content");
 document.appendChild(h1);
 return document;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use a W3C DOM Document/Element/Node? Can't you use Saxon's native tree model? Anyway, don't create a new `Processor` in your call, use the existing one: `context.getConfiguration().getProcessor()`, then use a DocumentBuilder created from that processor.

Comment: So I added `Configuration.ApiProvider p = new Processor();      configuration.setProcessor(p);` in the `TransformerFactory` `Configuration`. In the `call` function, I did cast `Configuration.ApiProvide` to `Processor` and was able to call `newDocumentBuilder` from that. It returns a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder` ; using it to wrap the DOM node returns the SXXP0004 error. Of course, the `buildSomeDocument` method uses a different DocumentBuilder as `...s9api.DocumentBuilder`cannot be cast to `org.w3.dom.DocumentBuilder`

Comment: As for your suggestion of using Saxon's native tree model, I can't, having to stick to standard DOM functions.

Comment: Perhaps add more of your Java code to the question, I don't understand at what point you are having a TransformerFactory, I assumed using Saxon 12 and its extension functions you are dealing with s9api where you have e.g. `Processor processor = new Processor()` to start with and e.g. `processor.registerExtensionFunction`. Is the error message the same as before? That would suggest you are still dealing with two different `Processor`s/`Configuration`s.

Comment: If you want to use a W3C DOM with Saxon, make sure you use a namespace aware one i.e. use `dbf.setNamespaceAware(true)` before creating a DocumentBuilder. Can't tell for sure whether using namespace aware node creation methods e.g. createElementNS instead of createElement is also needed or safer at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling out my suggestion from the comment, the code is e.g.

```java
public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
      return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
          @Override
          public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
              Processor processor = (Processor)context.getConfiguration().getProcessor();
              DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
              Document document = null;
              try {
                  document = buildSomeDocument();
              } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }
              XdmNode wrapped = documentBuilder.wrap(document);
              return wrapped.getUnderlyingNode();
          }
      };
}
```

The code to set up the processor and register the extension function:

```java
Processor processor = new Processor();

processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration().setProcessor(processor);

processor.registerExtensionFunction(new MyExtensionFunctionDefinition());
```

All visible in https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonHE12ExtensionFunctionDomNodeExample1.

Comment: Yes ! I missed the `processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration().setProcessor(processor);`  (which seems rather convoluted to me !) as you can see in my edited question. Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: @AliceOualouest, I agree that is seems a bit convoluted and counter-intuitive that, given s9api, the `Processor processor = new Processor();` creates a new `Processor` with an underlying `Configuration`, that you need to set it then on that configuration. But otherwise I got a null from `context.getConfiguration().getProcessor()` so for the sample to work (only tested with Saxon 12.3) it seems necessary. Perhaps Michael Kay will come along later to enlighten use with an easier way.